# Where _bss_start is define Linux kernel source

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

I am going through Linux kernel source and found _bss_start C varianle in one of assembly files but could not find where it is actully defined and intialized.

It looks like _bss_start is the starting address of the bss segment but where and how it is intialized with values in kernel source ,I am looking into linux source 2.6.25.

I looked into file asm-generic/section.h where it is defined like below

```
 extern char _bss_start[]
```

but how _bss_start is defined ,is it DS register is being used to intialized it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`__bss_start`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__bss_start) is defined and initialized by the linker. It references the [.bss section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) of the image, which contains statically allocated variables.

Here is a stripped down example of the linker script defining these symbols:

```
.bss : {
    __bss_start = .;      /*< __bss_start references this position in the file */
    *(.bss)               /*< The actual contents of the section */
    *(COMMON)             /*< The actual contents of the section */
    _ebss = . ;           /*< _ebss references this position in the file */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dark but when I go and see linker script ,its something like "_bss_start=.;" Is this value intialized at run time??

Comment: `.` references the current position in the linked binary at that point in the linker script. It is statically placed in the image wherever you used the symbol `__bss_start`.

Comment: But @Dark still not convinced how a value comes into symbol _bss_start,it should be some hexa number ,isn't it??

Comment: bss_resource.start=virt_to_phys(&_bss_start);Something like this @Dark? It would be great if you let me know in detail.

Comment: I can't give more detail. I have told you everything there is to tell. It is not C. It is a CONSTANT. It is calculated at compile time and the linker places it in the resulting kernel image.

Comment: on the point where you mention its not C ,given link http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html tell variable with _(underscore) consider as C variabe

Comment: So you can access it from C, yes. It is not a feature of C. It is a feature of the linker. You can also access it from any other language that goes through the linker, such as from ASM.

Comment: The free-electrons.com URL is dead.